# Region of $ \frac{1-x}{1-y} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

In the book "Ordinary Differential Equations: An Elementary Textbook for Students of Mathematics, Engineering, and the Sciences" by Tenenbaum. He defines a region as follows:

> A set in the plane is called a region if it satisfies the following two conditions:
>
> 1. Each point of the set is the centre of a circle whose entire interior consists of points of the set
> 2. Every two points of the set can be joined by a curve which consists entirely of points of the set

Now, in Exercise 2, section 8 he ask to determine the domain of $ z = \frac{1-x}{1-y} $. The domain is all pairs of points $ (x,y) $ in the set of real numbers such that $ y \neq 1 $.

Later, he says this is a region. However, I think it must be wrong as the vertical plane intersecting the line $ y = 1 $ cuts the plane XY and makes the second point of the definition of region unfeasible as we can have two points of the set on opposite sides that can't be joined by a curve which consists entirely of points of the set. Let's say (0, -1) and (0, 3)

Is an errata or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right (except that $y=1$ is a line rather than a plane).

Comment: Are you sure that the function is defined on real numbers? If, instead, x,y can be generic complex numbers than $\{y\ne 0\}$ is a region

Comment: @AlessandroCigna I am. It's the beginning of the book so he hasn't gone into complex numbers yet

Comment: On the complex plane the set $\{(x,y):x,y\in \mathbb R, y\neq 1\}$ would be considered a domain (or region, in this case) since we can map any two ordered pairs (with some funky mapping). In this case, however, i think you are right. I don't believe it's a region.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @JoséCarlosSantos. I tried to improve the description.